# JED in no_mode by default

Tags: text-processing, application

How do I ensure that JED editor always uses `no_mode` by default?

I've tried this:

```
Default_Mode = &no_mode;
```

But it still opens files with unknown extensions like .rules in text_mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Default_Mode = &no_mode;
```

Does indeed work but it wasn't when I did something like `sudo jed /etc/udev/rules.d/99-somerule.rules`

For that I obviously need to also have the above setting in `/root/.jedrc`